# Qt SIGNAL-SIGNAL connection the new Way

Tags: qt, signals

I use the old connection syntax until now. Today I want to change my project to new connection syntax like this:

```
#include <QDebug>

class Telefon : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
  public:
    void letRing() {
      qDebug() << "letRing";
      emit ring();
    }

  signals:
    void ring();
  public slots:
    void onRing() {
      qDebug() << "onRing";
    }
};

class Cable : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
  signals:
    void ring();
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Telefon *fon1 = new Telefon();
  Telefon *fon2 = new Telefon();
  Cable *cable = new Cable();

  // old connection way
  // connect(fon1,  SIGNAL(ring()), cable, SIGNAL(ring()));
  // connect(cable, SIGNAL(ring()), fon2,  SLOT(onRing()));

  // new connection way
  QObject::connect(fon1,  &Telefon::ring, cable, &Cable::ring);    // <-- This is the problem
  QObject::connect(cable, &Cable::ring,   fon2,  &Telefon::onRing);

  fon1->letRing();

  return 0;
}
```

The compiling went well with no errors. But the telefon never rings :(

Output should be:

```
letRing
onRing
```

But it is:

```
letRing
```

I Dig into the Qt code and found that SIGNAL-SLOT connections where valid but SIGNAL-SIGNAL connections don't work this way. Beside it generate no error while compiling. Is there a way to connect SIGNALs the new way/syntax?

Comment: I add the example

Comment: Can't reproduce.  When compiled and linked against the `moc` generated code the example shown works as expected for me (Qt 5.12.3 and g++ 9.1.1 on Linux).

Comment: @Marcus add `#include "main.moc"` at the end of the file